# Is not having 'named' timezone support common in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, best-practices, timezone

I'm trying to set the timezone the database uses using:

```
"SET time_zone = 'UTC';
```

Whilst this works on my development server it doesn't work on my staging server; I get this error:

```
General error: 1298 Unknown or incorrect time zone: 'UTC'
```

Now I am assuming this is because I cannot see a `mysql` table on the staging server with the respective timezones, whilst it *does* exist on my development server.

**Edit:** Apparently it *does* exist on the staging server but the user I am logged in with for that database can't see it, so I guess MySQL can't find the data.

I'm building some software that others will be using on their servers, so I will have no idea if they will have the aforementioned `mysql` table.

With that said, should I avoid using `"SET time_zone = 'UTC';` in software that others will use?

If so, what is the correct way to handle this situation?

Is doing something like:

```
"SET time_zone = '+0:00';
```

...the better way to do it?

Comment: Submit a bug at http://bugs.mysql.com .

Comment: @RickJames What bug?

Comment: That it won't take 'UTC'.  But first, check that you have installed [TimeZone Support](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html).

Comment: @RickJames Check the edit I made earlier. :)